# How to get/crawl all the reviews of apps on play store or app store, I am just getting first 40 reviews?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-play, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using python for this.
I am going to play store url for an app then parse the body into tree, extracting data with xpath

```
reviews = parsed.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]//div[@class="review-body with-review-wrapper"]')
```

and then wrting it in a file

```
reviewFile = rev.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9.,\' ]+', '', reviewFile.text_content().replace('  Full Review  ','').strip())
    print('writing reviewFile'+reviewFile)
```

But with this I am able to get only first 40 reviews on the google play store instead of all reviews.

After first 40 reviews are displayed Google Play starts to load more reviews by pinging http://play.google.com/store/getreviews

Comment: Can you provide a link? It seems like dynamically generated content which scrapy can't handle without splash

Comment: Have you **checked the terms of service**?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida: For example I am trying to get all reviews for the Duolingo app from: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo&hl=en

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes I did, it has no mention of anything relevant

Answer (score 1):

You must send a post request to https://play.google.com/store/getreviews. The post request must include the following header:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
}
```

Your query (pagenumber, review sorting, etc.) should be a urlencoded string, like:

```
payload = 'reviewType=0&pageNum=' + pagenum + '&id=' + appid + '&reviewSortOrder=2&xhr=1'
```

You can then send this request using the request module:

```
text = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers).text
```

**Note:** The response is actually in the form of a list with the html inside it that you will have to parse and it has this weird **)]}'** thing at the beginning that you will have to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a third-party solution like SerpApi. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all rich structured data for you.

With this API you can retrieve up to 199 reviews per page, and then use `next_page_token` to get the rest.

Example python code for retrieving Duolingo reviews (available in other libraries also):

```rb
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_play_product",
  "store": "apps",
  "gl": "us",
  "product_id": "com.duolingo",
  "all_reviews": "true"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
{
  "reviews": [
    {
      "title": "Peter D.",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GioS2BahCbwDtFkNTX7yPpVgVakurE2KKQroYxM8A",
      "rating": 4,
      "snippet": "This is actually kind of fun but Im missing lots because the \"speak this sentence\" feature is useless. It's absolutely faulty. No matter myself or a native speaker trying it always says \"that doesn't sound right\". It's really a key feature of the lessons and it's irritating to use this app when paid for and not have full use. I should give 3 stars because I'm paying for what I can't use, but I like Duolingo. Please fix this or lower your cost. It's been this way for the last 6 months. FIX.",
      "likes": 30,
      "date": "November 28, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "Howard Liu",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Ggq72VDo-mOYz8fs25CXF5-FSFBjQn6vprLC4R4gA",
      "rating": 2,
      "snippet": "The competitive nature of the league system is annoying, especially when the timed quizzes are so uneven in difficulty, in a way that has nothing to do with the vocabulary - occasionally you'll roll through an entire set of multiple choice questions, and other times you'll get nothing but arrange-the-sentence puzzles with ten or fifteen elements. And naturally there's a pay-to-win element. Very off-putting. There's probably a better way to learn Chinese, and when I find it, I'm bailing.",
      "likes": 4,
      "date": "November 29, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "Leah H",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj623ECH79z8q4IADL8p69weaQKtRxj76xw1Zo6GA",
      "rating": 1,
      "snippet": "Learn sentences such as \"I am not an apple\" and \"i want to eat her hair\" while being forced to look at the most hideous animated characters you've ever seen, with no way to turn them off or disable distracting animations. I used to love this app. It's gone so far downhill it's quite sad, really. I'm moving to Babbel. It's 100% ad free for starters... and doesn't have hideous, corporate-approved characters who boo you and shake their head if you make a mistake.",
      "likes": 6,
      "date": "November 29, 2021"
    },
    ...
  ]
  "serpapi_pagination": {
    "next": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?all_reviews=true&engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&next_page_token=CpIBCo8BKmkKR_8AwEEujFG2rWAA___-9zuazVn_rKyBmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8-bzZ2anJnLxp3Kxc7FiZLFzMvLzMbKycvMzcbMy83Jy8zLyP_-ECghngOwC6nzNQdQAFoLCasS-6dWkoDhEANg_d-19AUyIgogCh5hbmRyb2lkX2hlbHBmdWxuZXNzX3FzY29yZV92MmE&product_id=com.duolingo&store=apps",
    "next_page_token": "CpIBCo8BKmkKR_8AwEEujFG2rWAA___-9zuazVn_rKyBmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8-bzZ2anJnLxp3Kxc7FiZLFzMvLzMbKycvMzcbMy83Jy8zLyP_-ECghngOwC6nzNQdQAFoLCasS-6dWkoDhEANg_d-19AUyIgogCh5hbmRyb2lkX2hlbHBmdWxuZXNzX3FzY29yZV92MmE"
  }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-play-product-api) for more details.

Test the search live on the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_play_product&product_id=com.duolingo&gl=us&store=apps&all_reviews=true).

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*